# превратить массив строк в глубокий объект

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

допустим есть массив строк`['kitchen', 'angle', 'leftSide']`

как создать функцию, которая принимая этот массив, возвращает объект с такой структурой:

```
{
    kitchen: {
        angle: {
            leftSide: null
        }
    }
}
```

**ВАЖНО!  Количество строк в массиве может быть разной, функция должна принимать одномерный массив строк с любым количеством элементов.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let arr = ['kitchen', 'angle', 'leftSide'];
let obj = o = {};

arr.forEach(key => {o = o[key] = {}});

console.log(obj);
```

---

```js
let test = ['kitchen', 'angle', 'leftSide'];
let last;

let obj = test.reduce((o, val) => {
  if (typeof last == 'object')
    last = last[val] = {};
  else
    last = o[val] = {};

  return o;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

Причин для холивара нет, но по условию вернее этот ответ.

```
leftSide: null
```

```js
let arr = ['kitchen', 'angle', 'leftSide'];

let result = arr.reverse().reduce((acc, item)=> { acc = {[item]: acc? {...acc} : null}; return acc;}, null)

console.log(result);
```

ну или более короткий аналог

```js
let result = ['kitchen', 'angle', 'leftSide'].reverse().reduce((a,i)=>({[i]:a||null}),null);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот ещё сократил