# Создание объекта из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Подскажите, как из массива:

```
let arr = [111, 222, 333, 444]
```

создать объект вида:

```
{
  111 : {
    222 : {
      333 : {
        444 : 'some value'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

используя только циклы for, без использования всяких наворотов типа reduce, reduceRight и т.д.

Comment: Оказалось что решение уже есть на Стоке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234706/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так сделать

```js
let arr = [111, 222, 333, 444]

let result = 'some value';

for(let index = arr.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
  result = {[arr[index]]: result};
}
 

console.log(result);
```

Comment: В шапке темы же написано "без использования всяких наворотов типа reduce" а вы все равно используете reduce

Comment: с использованием reduceRight можно еще проще сделать " arr.reduceRight((a, b) => a = { [b]: a }, 'asdasdasd') "

Comment: @ПавелИванов А так сойдет?

Comment: То что нужно. Огромное спасибо. Пытался рейтинг сообщения плюсануть- не смог. Но ответом вроде получилось отметить.